# When plotly bar chart textposition = "inside", how do I shift the text inside the bar?

Tags: r, bar-chart, r-plotly

**Code:**

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

xValues <- c("drug1","drug2","drug3","drug4","drug5")

yValues <- c(5,10,15,20,25)

bar <- plot_ly(x = yValues,
               y = xValues,
               type = 'bar',
               orientation = 'h',
               text = xValues,
               textposition = "inside",
               insidetextanchor = "middle",
               insidetextfont = list(color = '#000000'),
               showlegend = F) %>% 
         layout(
                xaxis = list(title = "Studies"),
                yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE,showline = FALSE,showticklabels = FALSE))
bar
```

**Output:**
[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A1Fg.png)

**When I try to use insidetextanchor with plot_ly(), it doesn't register that I'm asking it to move the text to the middle. What am I doing wrong?**

---

According to the [Figure Reference for Plotly R](https://plotly.com/r/reference/) (bar traces section):

**insidetextanchor**

Type:  enumerated , one of (  `"end"`  |  `"middle"`  |  `"start"`  )
*Default:*   `"end"`

Determines if texts are kept at center or start/end points in `textposition` "inside" mode.

Comment: Very strange, your code works for me? [Plot](https://i.imgur.com/Kx0THsg.png). Maybe try restarting your R session? Don't forget to save anything important. I'm using `plotly_4.9.2`. You can check your version with `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this code text appears in the middle as expected. Update packages and R